# Regex to convert URLs to HTML <a href> hyperlinks in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of URLs in a text file I am trying to change to HTML, but I'm failing miserably.

My URLs are in this format:

```
http://mydomain.com/here-are-my-links.html
```

Does anybody know of a regex search/replace command I can run in Notepad++ to change my URL list to this format:

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/here-are-my-links.html">here are my links</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the regex

`(http://mydomain.com/(.*?)\.html)`

and replace it with

`<a href="\1">\2</a>`

---

If you want to change `-` into `space` you can do this

`-(?=[^<>]*?</a>)`

and replace it with

Comment: (This doesn't quite get the right format, see the edited question. Also, `-` should become spaces.)

Comment: Excellent, thank you - it worked great.  Is it possible to remove the '-' symbols from the link text at all and replace with spaces?

Comment: Excellent, I really appreciate the answer and the speed it was provided.  Thank you.

Comment: @user1061571 i have written it in another way like this `and replace it with`

Comment: I'm missing the obvious here I know, but any chance of just going through this one more time please?  I run the first search/replace in notepadd++ and it works great.  I then try to run the second search/replace to replace the '-' from the link text, but I can't see what I'm supposed to replace it with?  Hope that makes sense..

Comment: @user1061571 you need to replace it with a `space`

Comment: Ah, thank you :)  The problem is that it is removing the '-' from the actual link and not just the link text.

Comment: Fantastic, works great.  Again, thanks for taking the time to answer, it's appreciated.